# Deleting files under /etc/sudoer.d

Tags: permissions, sudo, delete

I granted another user account `sudo` privileges for running Docker commands by adding a file with their username directly under `/etc/sudoers.d`:

```
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/docker
```

I now want to revoke these privileges, I assume it is perfectly safe to just delete the file? So just:

```
sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/username
```

I have assumed many things in the past that have turned out to be incorrect... The file was originally created using `visudo` and has `-r--r-----` privileges (owner and group = root).

18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the only definition was that single user's access to a specific docker command set, then it is safe to remove the file.

In case you are afraid to do this, just go into the file, and put a `#` at the beginning of every line, which will disable whatever the permissions are specified in there.  That will have the same effective action (there's things that ZFS, etc. install in here sometimes and have similar setups).

If there are other definitions under there or in /etc/sudoers then you need to make sure those are still correct in syntax or sudo will break.  However, just removing the file will remove that permission set from the sudo privs.